# Double LIKE check

Tags: mysql

How would one go about creating query that will check comparison to a table in such manner than it needs two or more matches, regardless which but not same. I thought of creating a duplicate column

```
Col1 Col2
 A    A
 B    B
 C    C
```

and checking against both:
`LIKE CONCAT('%',table.col1,'%')` and `LIKE CONCAT('%',table.col2,'%')`
I am just not sure how to make sure that second `LIKE` isnt equivalent to first, because since they are equivalent both of the above statement will return positive. Yet I need to flag items like AB and not AA

Comment: Can you give an example of your data and the results that you are looking for?  The question is not clear, at least to me.  What is "two or more matches"?  To two different columns?  Two different rows?

Comment: I have a sentence, and i want to check if it has 2 words or more from a list. Word1 != Word2

Answer (score 1):

With this approach, you could add another `AND` clause to enforce this:

```
-- ...
WHERE foo LIKE CONCAT('%',table.col1,'%')
AND foo LIKE CONCAT('%',table.col2,'%')
AND table.col1 <> table.col2
```

I'm not sure that using a duplicate column is the best approach, though.

Comment: what other approach would you recommend?

Comment: that doesnt seem to work, when i ran the querry nothing got populated and yet i know there are double cases

Answer (score 0):

Ok, try something like this:

```
select s.*
from sentences s join
     words w
     on s.sentence like concat('%', w.word, '%') 
group by s.sentence
having count(*) > 1
```

This does the join to get the matches, and then filters out sentences that have fewer than two matches.

The use of `s.*` with `group by s.sentence` uses a MySQL (mis)feature called Hidden Columns, which might be useful in this case.